# I am missing a key ID for React button onClick

Tags: reactjs, class, button, onclick, key

When I click on the favorite button next to the list item, it changes all of them blue instead of just one "favorite" button. I know I am missing a key Id for the button function - but I can't figure it out

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

class MyStories extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      button: false
    };
    this.addFavorite = this.addFavorite.bind(this);
  }

  addFavorite = e => {
    this.setState({
      button: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return this.props.stories.map(t => (
      <div className="menu-inner-container">
        <p key={t.id}>
          <Link to={`/stories/${t.id}`}>{t.attributes.title}</Link>
          <button
            key={t.id}
            className={this.state.button ? "buttonTrue" : "buttonFalse"}
            onClick={this.addFavorite}
          >
            Favorites
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    ));
  }
}

//refactor - create a button that will allow for us to mark which our favorites are
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    stories: state.myStories
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyStories);
```

Comment: It looks like you're potentially sharing a single "favourite" state (i.e. `this.state.button`) for every item? You might want to maintain an array of of favourite states instead.

Comment: @miqh that sounds right, how would I do that in the className ?

Comment: Well, one approach is to make `this.state.button` an `object` (instead of a `boolean` as you've got) whose keys are the unique item identifiers and the values are the favourited state. Then the predicate in `className` becomes `this.state.button[t.id]`. You'd also need to modify your `addFavorite` signature such that it specifies which item to update the favourite state for (i.e. `addFavorite(id)`). This all assumes you want to maintain favourite state per item to begin with. If there should only be one favourite, there's no need to maintain the map.

Comment: This would have also worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this jsx

```
    <button key={ t.id } 
    className={this.state.button===t.id ? "buttonTrue": "buttonFalse"} 
    onClick={()=> this.addFavorite(t.id)}>Favorites</button>
```

function `addFavorite`

```
addFavorite = (id) => {
  this.setState({button: id})
}
```

Comment: @ChristinaW please accept/vote for this if it's helpful for you...Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

instead of using boolean value for button, use id of the clicked button. 

`<button key={ t.id } className={this.state.button === t.id ? "buttonTrue": "buttonFalse"} onClick={ (event) => this.addFavorite(event, t.id) }>Favorites</button>`

`addFavorite = (e, id) => {
  this.setState({
    button: id
  })`

`
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

```
this.state = {
  button: ''
}
this.addFavorite = this.addFavorite.bind(this);
```

}

`